# libusb on OSX returns less devices

Tags: swift, macos, libusb-1.0

I have a small xcode project that is mixed with c and Swift. The C side calling libusb_get_device_list returns less number of USB devices than it should. Only few times it returns the correct count. I checked the sandbox USB option ON. Also, disabled the signing. Still see it doing the same thing.

```
libusb_context *context = NULL;
libusb_device **list = NULL;

count = libusb_get_device_list(context, &list);
```

Comment: I think you are unlikely to get an answer to this question as it stands. The problem might be hardware related or environment related or anything really. I would suggest printing the list out as a start to see if which devices are missing will give you a clue.

Comment: You would need to show us how you're consuming these values, perhaps there's a bug there.